# Python looping issue with variable not being assigned to on certain iteration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Python, I am experiencing some bug where on a certain iteration a variable declared outside of a loop is not being assigned to only after a specific iteration.

Line 28 on the 8th iteration (x == 7) `interest` is miscalculated (probably not assigned to or something) and remains the same value for the rest of the iterations. The variable value seems to get stuck.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

loanAmount = 500000.0
interestRate = 3.5
loanTerm = 30.0

monthlyInterest = []
monthlyPrincipal = []
compoundingRate = float((((interestRate / 12) * 0.01) + 1))
loanTermMonths = float(loanTerm * 12)
preInterestMonthly = loanAmount / loanTermMonths
lastMonthWithInt = preInterestMonthly * compoundingRate

i = 1
sum = 0.0
while i < loanTermMonths - 1:
    lastMonthWithInt = lastMonthWithInt * compoundingRate
    sum += lastMonthWithInt
    i += 1

baseMonthly = sum / loanTermMonths

interest = 0.0
principal = 0.0
x = 0
while x < loanTermMonths - 1:
    interest = float((loanAmount - principal) * (compoundingRate - 1))   
    principal = baseMonthly - interest
    monthlyInterest.append(interest)
    monthlyPrincipal.append(principal)
    x += 1

x1 = np.arange(1, loanTermMonths)
y1 = np.array(monthlyInterest)
x2 = np.arange(1, loanTermMonths)
y2 = np.array(monthlyPrincipal)

plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "Interest") 
plt.plot(x2, y2, label = "Principal") 
plt.xlabel('months') 
plt.ylabel('$') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you enter the following statement right below

`monthlyPrincipal.append(principal)`

`loanAmount -= principal`,

then you will get the results you want.

EDIT: Just a suggestion, to get a more accurate monthly payment, I got from Wikipedia a formula to calculate the monthly payments given an initial loan amount.

Here is a program that uses that formula.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845238/python-looping-issue-with-variable-not-being-assigned-to-on-certain-iteration
loanAmount = 500000.0
interestRate = 3.5
loanTerm = 30 # 30 years
loanTermMonths = loanTerm * 12 # 360 months

i = interestRate / 12 * .01
n = loanTermMonths

# get cash flows, (monthly payments), for Present Value of loanAmount
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value
monthlyPayment = loanAmount * i / (1 - (1 + i)**(-n))

principal = loanAmount

monthlyInterest = []
monthlyPrincipal = []

for x in range(loanTermMonths):
    interest = principal * i
    monthlyInterest.append(interest)

    principalPortion = monthlyPayment - interest
    monthlyPrincipal.append(principalPortion)

    principal -= principalPortion

x1 = list(range(1, loanTermMonths+1))
y1 = monthlyInterest
x2 = list(range(1, loanTermMonths+1))
y2 = monthlyPrincipal

plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "Interest") 
plt.plot(x2, y2, label = "Principal")
plt.title('Loan Amortization')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('months') 
plt.ylabel('$') 
plt.show()
```

It is roughly the same as yours except for how it calculates the monthly payment.

Answer (score 0):

`>>> (100.0 - 6.805590751165351) * (1.0029166666666666 - 1)`

`0.2718170269757688`

`>>> (100.0 - 6.805590751165351) * (1.0029166666666667 - 1)`

`0.2718170269757688`

i think you need more precision